# "Is" or "Are" before a list with only singular nouns

Tags: grammar

Is it

```
 There **is** a sink, a tub and a shower.
```

or

```
  There **are** a sink, a tub and a shower.
```

when describing a list of items in a photo.

There are lots of similar examples that involve plurals and nouns joined by 'and' (including the ones provided by Grammarly). None of these uses a list of singular nouns.

[image: Explanatin from Grammarly]

Comment: Doesn't the error text you included cover it?

Comment: No, it doesn't. If I thought it did, then I wouldn't have included it. 

The error text examples use compound subjects which would make it plural. It is correct in that particular instance but don't apply to a list of purely singular nouns.

Answer (score 1):

I think the second one is correct because you are describing three objects in the sentence:

> There are a sink, a tub, and a shower in this photo.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule is that the subject determines whether the verb is singular or plural

> John is a farmer and a butcher (John, singular so "is")

However English has a special form, used for asserting existance. "There is/are/was/were..."

In this case the subject is the dummy pronoun "There" and the plural verb is determined by the complement

> There is one dog

> There are two dogs.

Remember if the noun phrase is treated as two or more distinct items, it is plural

> There are a farmer and butcher in the room talking to each other.  (two people)

But if it refers to one thing then use singular.

There's a farmer and butcher in the room. My husband, John, is both.

(Grammarly flags this last example as it can't understand the context)

In you case, there are three items: so use "There are"

But....  because this is backwards (the phrase which determines the verb form coming after the verb) It is quite common for native speakers to get this wrong, especially when talking

> There's a sink ... and a bathtub.

When he started the sentence he was only going to say "sink" but he changed his mind, but by then it was too late.